# Debugging simple operation Kotlin Android Studio

Tags: kotlin, bit-shift

```
val strValue = (characteristic.value[1].toUInt().shl(8) or characteristic.value[2].toUInt()).toUShort()
```

This code works well to 127. Then it moves to 65408. It looks:

123

124

125

126

127

65408

65409

65410

Basically this code connects two uint8 and makes uint16. I dont know what is happening

Comment: Impossible to say without know what your inputs are.

Comment: Input is correct value from 1 to 999. It is uint16 divided to two uint8. Then i connect them with bit shift and i again got uint16. Please help me i am running out of thoughts

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. Are you sure your input is correct? https://pl.kotl.in/ak0VhrZYX